# Gadget OAuth2 Authorization

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-gadget, google-tasks-api

I am developing a gadget (`html, JS`) to run inside ([`Google Calendar page`](http://calendar.google.com)).
I need to show user's tasks there so I need a connection to `Google Task Api`.
I need to use `OAuth2` authorization and such requests as:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists 
GET https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/lists/tasklist/tasks
```

Unfortunately I haven`t found description or samples for gadgets with`OAuth2` authorization.

Could you please tell me what will the `OAuth2` section look like in this case?

```
 <OAuth2>
   <Service name="[service_name]">
      <Authorization url="https://.../authorize"/>
      <Token url="https://.../oauth2/token"/>
   </Service>
 </OAuth2>
```

Could you please approve this code for a request? `(JS)`

```
 function loadContents(){           
   var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists?alt=json";            
   var params = {};
   params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.CONTENT_TYPE] = gadgets.io.ContentType.JSON;
    params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.AUTHORIZATION]=gadgets.io.AuthorizationType.OAUTH2;
   params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.METHOD] = gadgets.io.MethodType.GET;     
   params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.OAUTH_SERVICE_NAME] ="[service_name]";       
   var callback = function (response) { 
     if (response.oauthApprovalUrl) {
       ...                 
     }                      
   };             
   gadgets.io.makeRequest(url, callback, params);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is - using OAuth instead of OAuth 2.0.

OAuth section should be:

```
 <OAuth>
      <Service name="google">
        <Access url="https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken" method="GET" /> 
        <Request url="https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks" method="GET" /> 
        <Authorization url="https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken?oauth_callback=http://oauth.gmodules.com/gadgets/oauthcallback" /> 
      </Service>
    </OAuth>
```

The request is `[JS]`:

```
 var params = {};
 url = "https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists?key=YOUR_API_KEY";
      params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.CONTENT_TYPE] = gadgets.io.ContentType.JSON;
      params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.AUTHORIZATION] = gadgets.io.AuthorizationType.OAUTH;
      params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.OAUTH_SERVICE_NAME] = "google";
      params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.OAUTH_USE_TOKEN] = "always";
      params[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.METHOD] = gadgets.io.MethodType.GET;
```

To use OAuth1 for Google Tasks API we need an 
[API key](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/auth).

Answer (score 1):

The Gadgets API framework doesn't support OAuth2. The Tasks API does support OAuth1 however, so you may still be able to get things working.